# symfony doctrine pdo odbc driver

Tags: symfony, pdo, odbc

I would like to configure connection to sqlserver from my symfony config file.

PHP connection work fine

```
$mssqldriver == '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}';
PDO("odbc:Driver=$mssqldriver;Server=Myserver,Myport;Database=Mydatabese;", $username, $password)
```

`Symfony config.yml`*(doesn't work!)*

**MSSQL**:

```
        driver:    pdo_sqlsrv
        host:     '%database_host3%'
        port:     '%database_port3%'
        dbname:   '%database_name3%'
        user:     '%database_user3%'
        password: '%database_password3%'
        charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: The PDO_SQLSRV extension is only compatible with PHP running on Windows. For Linux, see ODBC and » Microsoft's SQL Server ODBC Driver for Linux.source(http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)

Comment: It's an outside link, but my first search on google was this, https://dunglas.fr/2014/01/connection-to-a-ms-sql-server-from-symfony-doctrine-on-mac-or-linux/  Do you think it could help you ?

Comment: @pbenard , (sorry for my english), I think that this solution is not adapted form linux server. i had to modify vendor to make it work! concerned file Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib